# View.Visible working fine in Marshmallow but not working on Kikat

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

`View.Visible` is working fine the above version 5.0 in android but not working on Kitkat version. Not getting actual problem, Am searched a lot but not getting solution following is my code. Thank you in advance

```
 public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
      Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stb_commands);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            HashMap data = new HashMap();
            new mainActivity.AsyncTaskGenre(data).execute();
            break;
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String request = "http://";
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(request, "POST",data);
            return json.toString();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("RESULT ",""+s);
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                String error = jsonObject.get("error").toString();
                Log.d("RESULT", " " +error);
                if (error.equals("false"))
                {
                         button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not found...!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"check connection...!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be gone for every version of Android as your code tells to do that button1.setVisibility(View.GONE); in onCreate

Comment: Wrong coding comparison `if (error == "false")`

Answer (score 1):

**At first Compare your String Value Properly**

**Code Rectify**

```
if (error.equals("false")) // Why you set == ? 
            {
                     button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not found...!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

**FYI**

JSON Response is

> {"error":false,"1":{"id":6,"name":"Prash"}}

```
  String getError=jsonObject .getString("error").toString();
```

Now do your code

```
 if (error.equals("false")) 
            {
                     button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
```

Comment: @Parsh do test once again with using `equals` instead of `==`

Comment: @Parsh whats your logcat returns ?

Comment: Success..no errors..am not getting one thing this code is working fine with above 5.0 but not on kitkat and lower

Comment: @Parsh okay . please tell me what reply `Log.d("RESULT"` ??

Comment: Can you provide log what you are getting the result.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya .D/RESULT: {"error":false,"1":{"id":6,"name":"Prash"}}

Comment: One more thing guys my code is working fine with Marshmallow..is there any extra code which i have to add. For working fine with kitkat..?

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use `equels` instead of `==`

```
  if (error.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
                 button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not found...!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach debugger inside `onPostExecution()` method, and handle your conditions according to the response. as there must be something wrong in   `"jsonObject.get("error").toString()"`this.SO debug and handel your response you can.There is nothing wrong with `setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)`.

- rest your code seems to be fine. Give it a try and then reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem there is parsing issue thank you guys.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                String error = jsonObject.get("error").toString();
                Log.d("RESULT", " " +error);
                if (error.equals("false"))
                {
                   Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();
                    JSONObject currentDynamicValue;
                    int i=0;
                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        // loop to get the dynamic key
                        String currentDynamicKey = (String) keys.next();
                         if (!currentDynamicKey.equals("error")) {
                        // get the value of the dynamic key
                        currentDynamicValue = jsonObject.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
                        list.put(i, currentDynamicValue.get("command_id").toString());
                        i++;
                        final String command_id = currentDynamicValue.get("command_id").toString();
                        if(command_id.equals("0"))
                        {
                           button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Command not Found..!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                    }
```